# How to copy database into device in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i am developing app for blackberry which have Database as back-end. Database has some data so i am import that database from res to `sdcard` it is working perfectely in the simulator.
When i install `my app into device` then it is not working what can be the issue i could not understand. Below is my code..

**call Method**

```
DatabseCopy db=new DatabseCopy();
         db.copyFile("/nm.db","file:///SDCard/Databases/nm.db");
```

**Method**

```
 public  void copyFile(String srFile, String dtFile)
  {
        try
        {                   
                FileConnection fconn;                    
                fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(dtFile,Connector.READ_WRITE);

                if(!fconn.exists()) // if  file does not exists , create a new one
                {
                        fconn.create();
                }

                InputStream is = (InputStream)this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(srFile);
                OutputStream os =fconn.openOutputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0)
                {
                os.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
           is.close();
           os.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
           System.out.println("Exception"+e.getMessage())         ;
        }
}
```

Comment: which error did you get? if you want more come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Before trying this: you have to check the **SDCARD** is there or not and

> System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard")

Gives directly the path upto:

> file:///SDCard/

and then your filename;

```
private void copyFromResToSDCard() 
{       
    try 
    {
        InputStream is=(InputStream)getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ManualRecords.db");
        FileConnection fileconn=(FileConnection)Connector.open(System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard")+"ManualRecords.db");//Here set your Path with new fileName.db;
        if(fileconn.exists())
        {
            fileconn.delete();              
        }
        fileconn.create();
        byte data[]=new byte[is.available()];
        data=IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
        OutputStream os=fileconn.openOutputStream();
        os.write(data);
        fileconn.close();
        is.close();
        os.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("=============="+e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Enough;